# Variadic template expansion, inheritance, and std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, variadic-templates, unique-ptr

I have code that works like this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct A {
    virtual ~A() = default;
};

struct B : public A {
};

template<typename... Ts> struct C {
    C() : v_({new Ts...}) {}

    ...

    std::vector<A*> v_;
};

...

C<B, B, A> bba;
```

I'd like to use `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique` to avoid calling `new` explicitly and iterating over `v_` to delete it in destructor (`v_` will become `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>`) but can't figure out how to marry up `std::make_unique` with initialization list and variadic expansion (I suspect due to `std::unique_ptr` being move-only). Any suggestions?

Comment: It changes the question, but why `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>` and not, say `std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<Ts>...>`? If the collection is expected to change content signature, the constructor should be the template, not the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about a `C` constructor like the following ?

```
   // C++11 version (std::make_unique() unavailable in C++11)
   C()
    { 
      using unused = int[];

      v_.reserve(sizeof...(Ts));

      (void)unused { 0, ( v_.emplace_back( new Ts ), 0 )... };
    }

   // C++14 version
   C()
    { 
      using unused = int[];

      v_.reserve(sizeof...(Ts));

      (void)unused { 0, ( v_.emplace_back( std::make_unique<Ts>() ), 0 )... };
    }
```

The initial `0` in `unused` (suggestion from aschepler (thanks!)) permit the definition of

```
C<> etl;
```

with an empty type list for `C`.

Comment: I would add an extra 0 to `u` so that `C<>` works.  Why can't your "C++14 version" be used in C++11?

Comment: @aschepler - good idea the extra 0, I'll use it; the second one solution is C++14 only because (if I remeber correctly) `std::make_unique()` is a (starting from) C++14 feature.